# Saving json data in database posted from Android in laravel

Tags: json, laravel-5

First I tried this in order to post data from android:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input; 

    class JsonController extends Controller
   {
    public function jsonFunction(request $request){
    $requestObj=Input::all();
    if(count($requestObj) > 0)
    {
    $data=response()->json(['success'=>true,'request_param'=>$requestObj]);
    return $data;
   }
   else
  {
   return response()->json(['success'=>false,'error'=>'send some data']);

    }
    }

    }
```

on doing so and posting data from postman i got this on postman body:

```
    {
    "success": true,
   "request_param": {
   "title": "leave",
   "description": "i need a leave"
    }
   }
```

Now I tried saving data that i got from the device to database. For that I did this in my controller's function:

```
     public function jsonFunction(request $request){
     $requestObj=Input::all();
     if(count($requestObj) > 0)
       {
      $data=response()-      >json(['success'=>true,'request_param'=>$requestObj]);

     leave::insert([
       'title'=>$data('title'),
       'description'=>$data('description'),
    ]);
    }
     else
    {
     return response()->json(['success'=>false,'error'=>'send some data']);

     }
       return view('json');
         }
```

And it gave me this error: FatalThrowableError in JsonController.php line 19:
Function name must be a string.

I don't have enough knowledge about json encoding/decoding and saving to databse and retrieving those json_encoded information from database. Can anyone help please. Suggestion are humbly appreciated.

Comment: Is the data coming from android is in json?

Comment: @Ahmed Khan Yes. Data coming from postman is in json. I haven't tried using android yet.

Comment: Then you first need to decode your data. like this `$response = json_decode($request->getContent());`

Comment: @AhmedKhan could you please do in my code there?

Comment: ```public function jsonFunction(request $request){
     $response = json_decode($request->getContent());
 dd($response);
     if(count($requestObj) > 0)
       {
      $data=response()-      >json(['success'=>true,'request_param'=>$requestObj]);

     leave::insert([
       'title'=>$data('title'),
       'description'=>$data('description'),
    ]);
    }
     else
    {
     return response()->json(['success'=>false,'error'=>'send some data']);

     }
       return view('json');
         }```

Comment: try debugging it what you get?

Comment: @AhmedKhan okay will do it right away/

Comment: dd($response) gave null output in the browser.

Comment: try this 'dd($request)'

Comment: do you see the data which you are trying to send?

Comment: Request {#40 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure {#181 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure {#228 ▶}
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#42 ▶}
  +request: ParameterBag {#48 ▶}
  +query: ParameterBag {#48 ▶}
  +server: ServerBag {#44 ▶}
  +files: FileBag {#45 ▶}

Comment: +cookies: ParameterBag {#43 ▶}
  +headers: HeaderBag {#46 ▶}
  #content: ""
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/jsontest"
  #requestUri: "/jsontest?name=suzan"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "GET"
  #format: null
  #session: Store {#248 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
}

Comment: bunch of these thing came.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138324/discussion-between-suz-aann-shrestha-and-ahmed-khan).

Comment: @AhmedKhan yeah it came a bunch of request. you can try rentma.net/attendance/public/jsontest?someparameter